# wxGlade - Button to chose directory and file

Tags: python, wxpython, wxglade

i build my GUI with wxGlade. I think it is very comfortable but i´m looking for a widget/button which open a frame to chose a directory or file..

Can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify your button's event handler to open one of the following:

- wx.FileDialog
- wx.DirDialog
- wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog

There are good examples of each of these in the wxPython demo package. See also:

- http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1790040&
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/

Answer (score 0):

WxGlade does not directly support a adding a wx.FileDialog to your GUI. As someone answer you have to create and event linked to a button,menu,or toolbar then in your code enter the programming to open a filedialog and return text from it. What I normally do is use the toolbox button to create a generic dialog box and then name it open or save or something that will remind me that I will need to edit that piece of the wxGlade generated python code into and actual filedialog. That saves me a bit of time of typing ALL the code for a filedialog into the program.